# How to get bool function to do something in main

Tags: c++, function, boolean

What would I do to a bool function lets say that returned true  to do something in main? So if it returned true I would want it to add one to 'score' else if it returned false I would not like it to add one to 'score'. Thanks!

```
int main{

callBoolfunction();
score ++
}
```

Comment: Huh? `score ++` is not a correct statement. Missing `;`. Please post the code you have written. Including the function '`callBoolfunction`.

Comment: You will need to consult a basic programming and C++ tutorial before posting trivially answerable questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (callBoolfunction())
    score++;
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case:

```
score += callBoolfunction();
```

Explantation: `bool` simply devaluates to any number type.

Comment: While this works, I'd not suggest it to beginners.

Comment: @leemes But it does work, and is extremely simple and readable, because `bool` simply devaluates to any number type (eg. `int32_t`, `uint64_t`, etc.).

Comment: An `if` block is more readable (intuitive), since intuition says that the value only changes "if the function returns true", which is what an `if` block does and exactly how the question is expressed in words (he didn't say to add zero if it returned false).

Comment: @leemes Well... That makes some sense, but I do believe my code is gonna be optimised better, though.

Comment: And I do believe that every decent compiler optimizes away the conditional branch resulting in the same code (if optimizations are enabled). And again, this is a beginner's question, so the answer shouldn't really contain manual micro optimizations.